# Chartjs showing labels for bidimensional array

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I wanna add labels to my bar chart and for it I'm also using chartjs-plugin-datalabels. The issue is that my data comes from two arrays joined together.

[image: bars with labels]

I'd like to just see the "y" number and nothing else. I guess I have to add a parameter to options -> datalabels but I couldn't understand the documentation for my use case. Thanks!

This is the js I'm using.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
moment.locale('es'); 
moment().format('L'); 
Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});

// gráfico de barras IBM


var color = Chart.helpers.color;
var entregas_ibm_dia = @json($ar_entregas_ibm_dia);
var reversas_ibm_dia = @json($ar_reversas_ibm_dia);


var ctx3 = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

var myBar = new Chart(ctx3, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Entregas',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: entregas_ibm_dia
        }, {
                label: 'Reversas',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: reversas_ibm_dia
        }]
        },
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                        position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Reversas v/s abastecimiento'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'day',
                             displayFormats: {
                                day: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
                            },
                            tooltipFormat: 'll'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        display: function(context) {
                                return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
});
</script>
```

EDIT: I worked around the issue by using one dimensional arrays and putting dates on labels and adding it as a tick source on the x Axis' scale:

```
ticks: {
    source: 'labels'
},
```

The problem is when the array has data in one of the datasets and not in the other.

Comment: Please upload your relevant code

Comment: Done. I added the script I'm using within a Blade (laravel) template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Not really rocket science:

```
plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                  formatter: function(value, context) {
                                return value['y'];
                    }
            }
         }
```

Basically within the formatter value is the label's content itself for every piece of data. I found this within [the docs](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/formatting.html#custom-labels) but my use case wasn't the same and I mistook the display option for formatter.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer! I have a similar problem, but i want to show the labels for each bar. Is it possible ? Code : https://jsfiddle.net/sipon/j63bus49/23/

Comment: @AlexanderS. 
*datalabels: {
        formatter: function (value) {
                  return value['tagging_count'];                  
          },
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold',
          size: '15'
        }
      }*